# 500 Internal Server Error on my wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, plugins, internal-server-error

A client of mine uploaded a plugin to his wordpress website.

Since then this error shows, we can't login on the website, nothing.

***Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@kosibaycampandtours.co.za to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
Apache Server at kosibaycampandtours.co.za Port 443***

I have tried to rename the .htaccess but then the error shifts to 404 Not Found error.

I've tried to disable all the plugins or to disable the plugins one by one but no luck

**This is his domain https://www.kosibaycampandtours.co.za/**

I am open to try anything please. If anyone needs any information just let me know.

Comment: Do you have access to his apache logs? 
The exact error will be recorded in there. I can only speculate that im being sent to a url thats not part of wordpress meaning the .htaccess is not pointing to the right place.

Comment: I am not sure if this is correct. This was the latest error, all of the previous errors are the same

Comment: 2020-11-06 09:10:47 Error  197.185.99.87 Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace. AH00124